# Can Swashbuckle generate OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swashbuckle

Using Swashbuckle in ASP.NET core 2.2 generates Swagger specification version 2, but now a change to version 3 specification is required (OpenAPI 3.0)

Where should a code specification be added to make it happen? And, is this supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Now the Version 5 is out of prerelease it is no longer mandatory to install the 5.0.0 release candidate version of Swashbuckle.  Simply running

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
```

Will be enough to ensure you are using the latest version of Swashbuckle with OpenApi 3.0 support.

**Previous Answer**

Version 5 of Swashbuckle supports OpenApi 3.0.  This is currently in prerelease at the moment, but you can obtain it from the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/5.0.0-rc2

Just run the following command in your package manager console

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 5.0.0-rc2
```

Comment: This works fine, a minor changes has to be made because the **SwaggerDoc** method needed by **AddSwaggerGen**, now requires a `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo` for *Title*, *Description*, *Version*, *etc*. Previous package use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info`